# Display large data in chunks - PHP

Tags: php

I have a query to pull data in chunk using limit of 5000. The total number of data in the database is 20,000. My file below has been set as a supervisor script so it keeps running.

The query below only picks 5000 data every time it runs but is there a way i can let the data pick all the 20,000 data but it limit of 5000 ?

**file.php**

```
$sql = "select * from `table` where status='0' and flop='1' and switch='0' LIMIT 5000";
```

Comment: You need to make that query multiple times and change the limit so you fetch 5000 at the time but with different offsets. Here's a post about limit: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the same principle applies to databases with million rows ?

Comment: The amount is irrelevant. You usually use limit to paginate results etc.

Comment: For better performance rather than using a `LIMIT` with different values you should use a `WHERE` clause to select for ID between two values ( which change on each page )

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius - That assumes you'll always order the list on the id. If you order on any other column (that's not in some sequence), it wouldn't work.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - that would need to be a factor indeed but it'll speed up the paging considerably if there are millions of rows in the table

Comment: Don't forget to secure your query.

Answer (score 0):

You neet to specify OFFSET as well to return the next 5000 rows.

```
 select * from `table` where status='0' and flop='1' and switch='0' LIMIT 5000 OFFSET 10000
```

Likely, you should pass the offset as a parameter to your script